# JQuery layer append tag at the bottom instead of surround it's items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to surround all items inside the main-panel with a div but the div is just appended at the bottom of the class

I've yet tryed to use the following code but the result is that the div main-panel items are not surrounded by div close layer but it just appended it to the bottom as you can see on the screen

[image]

```
main_panel_height = $('.main-panel')[0].scrollHeight;
                $layer = $('<div class="close-layer"></div>');
                $layer.css('height', main_panel_height + 'px');
                $layer.appendTo(".main-panel");
```

I would be able to surround item inside the main-panel div.

Comment: have you heard of the wrap function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use wrapInner

```js
main_panel_height = $('.main-panel')[0].scrollHeight;
$layer = $('<div class="close-layer"></div>');
$layer.css('height', main_panel_height + 'px');
$('.main-panel').wrapInner($layer);
```

```css
.close-layer {color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-panel">main panel</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) is normally the best way to wrap elements using jQuery:

```js
main_panel_height = $('.main-panel')[0].scrollHeight;
$layer = $('<div class="close-layer"></div>');
$layer.css('height', main_panel_height + 'px');
$('.main-panel').wrap($layer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-panel">main panel</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the appendTo function (which adds to the end of the element):

```
$("#source").appendTo("#destination");
```

Example

```js
main_panel_height = $('.main-panel')[0].scrollHeight;
$layer = $('<div class="close-layer"></div>');
$layer.appendTo(".main-panel");
$layer.css('height', main_panel_height + 'px');
$layer.css('color', 'red');
$(".content").appendTo($(".close-layer"));
$(".footer").appendTo($(".close-layer"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-panel">main
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <footer class="footer"> footer</footer>
</div>
```